# How to bundle python libraries into addon?

Tags: python, add-on

I would like to distribute a Python addon that depends on two libraries: `Numpy` and `PyAudio`. I have seen all kinds of sorcery related to installing stuff via `pip` inside of Blender's Python interpreter, but this is different: I would want to generate a single .zip containing everything instead of messing around install-time. (As for example here: [Including 3rd party modules in a Blender addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8509/including-3rd-party-modules-in-a-blender-addon))

Is there a humane way to do this?

Comment: Isn't the question you linked to doing exactly that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including 3rd party modules in a Blender addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8509/including-3rd-party-modules-in-a-blender-addon)