# Bundling python library with addon

Tags: python, add-on

I'm making an add-on that uses the websocket library from python. Is there a way to include it in the add-on .zip file? Or do I have to add it to the site packages folder in blenders included python folder?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8509/including-3rd-party-modules-in-a-blender-addon

Comment: For recent versions of Blender (2.81 and later), you can install them through `pip`.

Comment: How would I make it install to the right place? It just installs to my user directory

Comment: You need to use subprocess and pass it the correct path to Blender's python interpreter. Unless somebody is faster I will write an answer later this evening.

Answer (score 22):

Blender includes `pip` on Windows since version 2.81, but not on other operating systems. Therefore, `pip` has to be installed through [`ensurepip.bootstrap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html#ensurepip.bootstrap) on Linux and macOS. This function can also be called on Windows, when pip is already installed. It will detect the existing installation of pip and won't modify it. Installing `pip` and Python packages through a script or an add-on may require that Blender is started with elevated privileges, for instance if Blender is located in `C:\Program Files`. Please note that this is generally not recommended for security reasons.

**Important:** [`ensurepip.bootstrap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html#ensurepip.bootstrap) [calls `pip` during for the installation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/34b0598295284e3ff6cedf5c05e159ce1fa54d60/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py#L35). `pip` sets the environment variable [`PIP_REQ_TRACKER` which is used as a temporary directory](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/326efa5c710ecf19acc3e1315477251a4cd4bd13/src/pip/_internal/req/req_tracker.py#L54). This directory doesn't exist anymore once [`ensurepip.bootstrap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html#ensurepip.bootstrap) finishes execution, but the environment variable `PIP_REQ_TRACKER` remains. This is a problem, because subsequent calls to `pip` will attempt to use the directory in `PIP_REQ_TRACKER`. It is necessary to remove `PIP_REQ_TRACKER` from the environment variables after calling [`ensurepip.bootstrap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html#ensurepip.bootstrap):

```
ensurepip.bootstrap()
os.environ.pop("PIP_REQ_TRACKER", None)
```

Once `pip` is installed, [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) can be used to to install the required packages. The path to Blender's Python interpreter is [`bpy.app.binary_path_python`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.html#bpy.app.binary_path_python). Installing a package, for example `matplotlib`*, would therefore be done in the following way:

```
subprocess.check_output([bpy.app.binary_path_python, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'matplotlib'])
```

<sub>*`matplotlib` is used as an example, since I wasn't sure which websocket package you were referring to.</sub>

---

**Important:** It's common courtesy to not connect to the internet or install packages without the explicit consent of the user.

The following add-on has a button in the preferences that allows the user to install the required Python packages. If the dependencies aren't installed, a panel with instructions is displayed in place of the add-on's operators. This approach respects the user's privacy and doesn't install packages without their permission.

User Preferences
[image: User preferences]

Instructions
[image: Instructions]

After successful installation of dependencies
[image: After installation of dependencies]

The `import_module(module_name, global_name=None)` functions allows to programmatically import modules based on their name and optionally specify a `global_name` under which the module can be accessed. For your own implementation it may not be necessary to use `importlib` and `globals()`, but it significantly reduces code redundancy if you need to import or install multiple modules. The installation of Python packages, as described above, is implemented in `install_pip()` and `install_and_import_module(module_name, package_name=None, global_name=None)`.

**Please check [GitHub](https://github.com/robertguetzkow/blender-python-examples/tree/master/add_ons/install_dependencies) for the updated version of this example add-on.**

```
#    Copyright (C) 2020  Robert Guetzkow
#
#    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
#    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
#    (at your option) any later version.
#
#    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#    GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#    along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>


bl_info = {
    "name": "Install Dependencies Example",
    "author": "Robert Guetzkow",
    "version": (1, 0, 2),
    "blender": (2, 81, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Sidebar > Example Tab",
    "description": "Example add-on that installs a Python package",
    "warning": "Requires installation of dependencies",
    "wiki_url": "https://github.com/robertguetzkow/blender-python-examples/add-ons/install-dependencies",
    "tracker_url": "https://github.com/robertguetzkow/blender-python-examples/issues",
    "support": "COMMUNITY",
    "category": "3D View"}

import bpy
import subprocess
from collections import namedtuple

Dependency = namedtuple("Dependency", ["module", "package", "name"])

# Declare all modules that this add-on depends on. The package and (global) name can be set to None,
# if they are equal to the module name. See import_module and ensure_and_import_module for the
# explanation of the arguments.
dependencies = (Dependency(module="matplotlib", package=None, name=None),)

dependencies_installed = False


def import_module(module_name, global_name=None):
    """
    Import a module.
    :param module_name: Module to import.
    :param global_name: (Optional) Name under which the module is imported. If None the module_name will be used.
       This allows to import under a different name with the same effect as e.g. "import numpy as np" where "np" is
       the global_name under which the module can be accessed.
    :raises: ImportError and ModuleNotFoundError
    """
    import importlib

    if global_name is None:
        global_name = module_name

    # Attempt to import the module and assign it to globals dictionary. This allow to access the module under
    # the given name, just like the regular import would.
    globals()[global_name] = importlib.import_module(module_name)


def install_pip():
    """
    Installs pip if not already present. Please note that ensurepip.bootstrap() also calls pip, which adds the
    environment variable PIP_REQ_TRACKER. After ensurepip.bootstrap() finishes execution, the directory doesn't exist
    anymore. However, when subprocess is used to call pip, in order to install a package, the environment variables
    still contain PIP_REQ_TRACKER with the now nonexistent path. This is a problem since pip checks if PIP_REQ_TRACKER
    is set and if it is, attempts to use it as temp directory. This would result in an error because the
    directory can't be found. Therefore, PIP_REQ_TRACKER needs to be removed from environment variables.
    :return:
    """

    try:
        # Check if pip is already installed
        subprocess.run([bpy.app.binary_path_python, "-m", "pip", "--version"], check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        import os
        import ensurepip

        ensurepip.bootstrap()
        os.environ.pop("PIP_REQ_TRACKER", None)


def install_and_import_module(module_name, package_name=None, global_name=None):
    """
    Installs the package through pip and attempts to import the installed module.
    :param module_name: Module to import.
    :param package_name: (Optional) Name of the package that needs to be installed. If None it is assumed to be equal
       to the module_name.
    :param global_name: (Optional) Name under which the module is imported. If None the module_name will be used.
       This allows to import under a different name with the same effect as e.g. "import numpy as np" where "np" is
       the global_name under which the module can be accessed.
    :raises: subprocess.CalledProcessError and ImportError
    """
    import importlib

    if package_name is None:
        package_name = module_name

    if global_name is None:
        global_name = module_name

    # Try to install the package. This may fail with subprocess.CalledProcessError
    subprocess.run([bpy.app.binary_path_python, "-m", "pip", "install", package_name], check=True)

    # The installation succeeded, attempt to import the module again
    import_module(module_name, global_name)


class EXAMPLE_OT_dummy_operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "example.dummy_operator"
    bl_label = "Dummy Operator"
    bl_description = "This operator tries to use matplotlib."
    bl_options = {"REGISTER"}

    def execute(self, context):
        print(matplotlib.get_backend())
        return {"FINISHED"}


class EXAMPLE_PT_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Example Panel"
    bl_category = "Example Tab"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        for dependency in dependencies:
            if dependency.name is None:
                layout.label(text=f"{dependency.module} {globals()[dependency.module].__version__}")
            else:
                layout.label(text=f"{dependency.module} {globals()[dependency.name].__version__}")

        layout.operator(EXAMPLE_OT_dummy_operator.bl_idname)


classes = (EXAMPLE_OT_dummy_operator,
           EXAMPLE_PT_panel)


class EXAMPLE_PT_warning_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Example Warning"
    bl_category = "Example Tab"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return not dependencies_installed

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        lines = [f"Please install the missing dependencies for the \"{bl_info.get('name')}\" add-on.",
                 f"1. Open the preferences (Edit > Preferences > Add-ons).",
                 f"2. Search for the \"{bl_info.get('name')}\" add-on.",
                 f"3. Open the details section of the add-on.",
                 f"4. Click on the \"{EXAMPLE_OT_install_dependencies.bl_label}\" button.",
                 f"   This will download and install the missing Python packages, if Blender has the required",
                 f"   permissions.",
                 f"If you're attempting to run the add-on from the text editor, you won't see the options described",
                 f"above. Please install the add-on properly through the preferences.",
                 f"1. Open the add-on preferences (Edit > Preferences > Add-ons).",
                 f"2. Press the \"Install\" button.",
                 f"3. Search for the add-on file.",
                 f"4. Confirm the selection by pressing the \"Install Add-on\" button in the file browser."]

        for line in lines:
            layout.label(text=line)


class EXAMPLE_OT_install_dependencies(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "example.install_dependencies"
    bl_label = "Install dependencies"
    bl_description = ("Downloads and installs the required python packages for this add-on. "
                      "Internet connection is required. Blender may have to be started with "
                      "elevated permissions in order to install the package")
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "INTERNAL"}

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        # Deactivate when dependencies have been installed
        return not dependencies_installed

    def execute(self, context):
        try:
            install_pip()
            for dependency in dependencies:
                install_and_import_module(module_name=dependency.module,
                                          package_name=dependency.package,
                                          global_name=dependency.name)
        except (subprocess.CalledProcessError, ImportError) as err:
            self.report({"ERROR"}, str(err))
            return {"CANCELLED"}

        global dependencies_installed
        dependencies_installed = True

        # Register the panels, operators, etc. since dependencies are installed
        for cls in classes:
            bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

        return {"FINISHED"}


class EXAMPLE_preferences(bpy.types.AddonPreferences):
    bl_idname = __name__

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator(EXAMPLE_OT_install_dependencies.bl_idname, icon="CONSOLE")


preference_classes = (EXAMPLE_PT_warning_panel,
                      EXAMPLE_OT_install_dependencies,
                      EXAMPLE_preferences)


def register():
    global dependencies_installed
    dependencies_installed = False

    for cls in preference_classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

    try:
        for dependency in dependencies:
            import_module(module_name=dependency.module, global_name=dependency.name)
        dependencies_installed = True
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        # Don't register other panels, operators etc.
        return

    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)


def unregister():
    for cls in preference_classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

    if dependencies_installed:
        for cls in classes:
            bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I will probably update the example add-on soon so nobody copies this into their add-on without reading the note.

Comment: Suggest something like `loader = importlib.util.find_spec(module_name)` to check if install required.

Comment: @batFINGER Sounds good, will improve/update the answer this weekend.

Comment: Or  `ModuleNotFoundError` Look forward to it.  Been coming at this from a different direction re checking for dependencies. (a deps tuple in bl_info dict would be handy, since it appears blender greps this out for fake module) This looks very handy for the next step. Consider it stolen, lol.

Comment: @batFINGER Posted the updated version.

Comment: This is cool and I want to star it. Would you consider hosting it on your github?

Comment: @Leander Sure, why not. I will create a repository this evening.

Comment: @Leander https://github.com/robertguetzkow/blender-python-examples

Comment: The answer currently does not include the trick to install without elevated permissions through `--user` and appending the user site-packages to `sys.path` because loading of the user site-packages was intentionally disabled (see [T76993](https://developer.blender.org/T76993) and [D6962](https://developer.blender.org/D6962)). It still works though, in case somebody needs this.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer! Is it possible to specify the version of the dependent library to be installed? For instance matplotlib 3.1.0 instead matplotlib 3.2.1

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland Yes, that is possible. You would have to modify [install_and_import_module](https://github.com/robertguetzkow/blender-python-examples/blob/4a3c99a843305b91e05db386559905b23cf6eb87/add-ons/install-dependencies/install-dependencies.py#L89) to take another optional argument, the version number. If the value is different from the default, then you can run `subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package_name_with_version], check=True, env=environ_copy)` where `package_name_with_version` is the concatenation of `package_name`, `==` and the version number.

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland Please keep in mind that this will cause trouble when there is already a more recent matplotlib version installed by another add-on though. Since there is no isolation between add-ons they all share the same modules and dependencies. Uninstalling the newer version is not an option as then the other add-on will likely fail to work.

Comment: Thank you @RobertGützkow for your answers. I'm encountering another issue. I tried pip install with `subprocess`, with both `sys.executable` and `bpy.app.binary_path_python` and my dependencies are being installed in `c:\users\my.user\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages` instead of `c:\program files\blender foundation\blender 2.93\2.93\python\lib\site-packages`. Blender is running as administrator... any idea why? :-/ Thanks again!

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland Could it be that the dependency was already installed in your user site-packages? You need to exclude the user site-packages otherwise pip will think the requirements are already satisfied (see https://github.com/robertguetzkow/blender-python-examples/tree/master/add_ons/install_dependencies#installing-the-package).

Comment: You're the best!