# How to Use Pillow (PIL) Inside Blender Addon?

Tags: python, scripting, image

I want to do

```
from PIL import Image
```

inside a Blender addon. But it throws this error at me:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

Thus I've tried to install Pillow via pip like this:

```
import subprocess
import ensurepip
ensurepip.bootstrap()
pybin = bpy.app.binary_path_python
subprocess.check_call([pybin, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'Pillow'])
```

But this doesn't work, either.

What am I doing wrong? :)

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? What version of Blender are you using?

Comment: Looks like I was mistaken and `pip` isn't included on the Linux release builds by default. Might have misunderstood Ray in [T71420](https://developer.blender.org/T71420). In that case it should work with ensurepip, which you would only have to run once. Does it at least find pip after running ensurepip?

Comment: `ensurepip` changes nothing. But it seems that `pip` is included in the snap version of Blender. But the import error that it can't find PIL persists

Comment: Again I forgot to tag you  @RobertGützkow

Comment: `ensurepip.boostrap()` and installing the package through subprocess works fine for me. Do you really not get any error message from ensurepip?

Comment: In a current version of Blender I could produce one particular problem. When `ensurepip.bootstrap()` is used followed by a pip install through subprocess, it fails to find a temp directory. This issue occurs on Linux and Windows.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168448/bundling-python-library-with-addon). You need to remove the environment variable `PIP_REQ_TRACKER` if you directly install a package with pip after running ensurepip.

Comment: @RobertGützkow I can't try it right now, but it seems really promising, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I finally had to copy my PIL package from C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\ and moved it into the Blender Foundation\Blender\2.8.2\python\lib\site-packages and everything started working fine.

Comment: That's the case because of the modification that you made to your Blender installation (see your other question). A clean and working installation of Blender comes with ensurepip, which allows to install pip, that can then install Pillow/PIL. The issue here is most likely that running `ensurepip.bootstrap()` sets an environment variable that makes a subsequent attempt to install a package with `pip` fail, because it tries to access a non-existent temp directory. This can be solved by removing the environment variable `PIP_REQ_TRACKER`.