# Blender 2.82 unable to find python package

Tags: python

I am trying to launch a script from blender 2.82 which uses PyQt5. PyQt5 module is installed and when running python3 from terminal and import PyQt5.QtCore, it works fine.

When i try to import from my blender script, it fails. I have tried to add in the script

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages")
```

which is the path where my python packages are installed, but still fails to import the module

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe It is in site-packages?

Comment: no, its actually dist-packages

Comment: Since Blender uses it's own interpreter and packages, I would suggest to install the package for Blender. See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168448/bundling-python-library-with-addon) for a way to do this from a Python script within Blender. You could also use your system's interpreter and modules, which would be another approach. However this would require compatible Python versions.

Comment: How can I use the system interpreter and modules? Isnt it possible to use blender interpreter adding system modules to the path?