# How to install matplotlib for use in Blender 3.2?

Tags: python

I want to use vi display.

I tried this way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LbPJt9upyXs
at the last step: this error appears to me:  `python not found!`

i have this version:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> print (np.__version__)
1.22.0
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5287/86891 ?

Comment: https://github.com/robertguetzkow/blender-python-examples/tree/master/add_ons/install_dependencies
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168448/bundling-python-library-with-addon/168482#168482

Comment: @Gorgious I've removed my comments, feel free to leave or remove your replies.

Comment: Vi display: no matplotib install..

Comment: I tried a lot to install it but i couldnt !

Comment: The message always appears for me when i write codes in the power shell: python not found